# Using SPARQL's URI( ) fn w/PREFIX & suffix containing slashes?

Tags: uri, sparql

I want to use a `PREFIX` to simplify URI creation.  Will welcome any advice that helps me build a mental model of what `PREFIX` is doing in a SPARQL query - it doesn't seem to a simple key/value replacement.

Here are some examples of what have tried.

## working

This works as expected and does what I want, except for not using a `PREFIX`.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    BIND ( URI("http:://www.foo.com/bar/01/grik/234") as ?s ) # (a) works fine
    ?s a ?o .
    # Here (a) works as expected. I'm binding ?s to a specific URI
    # for testing because otherwise it runs too long to debug my query logic.
}
LIMIT 10
```

## My failed `PREFIX` attempts

My actual prefix URI fragment is longer but this example shows the idea.

I want to put the first part of the above URI, **`http:://www.foo.com/bar/`**, in a `PREFIX` and use **`01/grik/234`** as a suffix.

Variations of this return nothing or error out on URI composition:

```
PREFIX foo: <http:://www.foo.com/bar/>
SELECT * WHERE {
    # I'm just running run one of these BIND statements
    # at a time; listing all of them here for easier visual comparison.
    # BIND ( URI(foo:01/grik/234) as ?s )                   # (b) Lexical error. Encountered "/" after "grik"
    # BIND ( URI(foo:"01/grik/234") as ?s )                 # (c) Encountered " <STRING_LITERAL2> "\01/grik/234"\""
    # BIND ( URI(foo:URI("01/grik/234")) as ?s )            # (d) Encountered "/" after "01"
    # BIND ( URI(foo:ENCODE_FOR_URI("01/grik/234")) as ?s ) # (e) Encountered "/" after "01"
    # BIND( URI(foo:ENCODE_FOR_URI("01/grik/234")) as ?s )  # (f) WARN  URI <http:://www.foo.com/bar/ENCODE_FOR_URI> has no registered function factory
    ?s a ?o .
}
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: you have to escape non alphanumeric characters in the name part of a prefixed URI by using the escape sequence char \ : `BIND ( URI(foo:01\/grik\/234) as ?s )`

Comment: *sigh*.  Thank you, @AKSW.  I tore some hair out on this.  Confirmed escaping backslashes works for me.  Will accept as answer if you post as such.

Comment: Do you really need to do this in the query itself?  If you simply need to construct a URI to substitute into your query many libraries have parameterised query support OR simply use your language of choices string concatenation/substitution capabilities

Comment: "really need?" No :-)   But my *desire* comes after hand crafting queries in the Jena web interface.  I want a short snippet I can copy / paste between windows (and from my program's output). The full URI is 80ish characters and I just find that clumsy to work with. (Am glad I pulled on the PREFIX thread, feel like I better understand SPARQL now thanks to AKSW's help).  Fwiw, my lang of choice is python, so I'm using rdflib - would welcome any advice you can offer for leveraging that (I am looking at prepared statements there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a IRI in its prefixed name form. The [W3C SPARQL recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) contains the following [section](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#prefNames)

> **4.1.1.1 Prefixed Names**
>
> The PREFIX keyword associates a prefix label with an IRI. A prefixed name is a prefix label and a local part, separated by a colon
>   ":". A prefixed name is mapped to an IRI by concatenating the IRI
>   associated with the prefix and the local part. The prefix label or the
>   local part may be empty. Note that SPARQL local names allow leading
>   digits while XML local names do not. SPARQL local names also allow the
>   non-alphanumeric characters allowed in IRIs via backslash character
>   escapes (e.g. `ns:id\=123`). SPARQL local names have more syntactic
>   restrictions than CURIEs.

Given that `/` is a non-alphanumeric character, the most important part here is

> SPARQL local names also allow the non-alphanumeric characters allowed
>   in IRIs via backslash character escapes (e.g. `ns:id\=123`).

Long story short, your query should be

```sql
PREFIX foo: <http:://www.foo.com/bar/>

SELECT * WHERE {  
    BIND ( URI(foo:01\/grik\/234) as ?s )
    ?s a ?o .
}
LIMIT 10
```